# Twitter API and json schema

Tags: json, api, twitter, schema

Is there any official or unofficial documentation of twitter api which includes json schemas? For example the following link contains only sample response

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/lists/members

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets

> ## Field Guide
>
> Consumers of Tweets should tolerate the addition of new
>   fields and variance in ordering of fields with ease. Not all fields
>   appear in all contexts. It is generally safe to consider a nulled
>   field, an empty set, and the absence of a field as the same thing.
>   Please note that Tweets found in Search results vary somewhat in
>   structure from this document.

Comment: There is a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom, which makes the table a little harder to use.